# Create symlink of every file in a folder tree

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

I need a Bash script that will create a symlink for every `*.mp3` file in folder X (and its subfolders), and store those symlinks in folder Y, without subfolders and probably skipping duplicates.

For the curious, this is to automate a radio station using [Libretime](https://github.com/LibreTime).

And sorry if this is a dumb question, I never used a Bash script.

Comment: Use `find` to to create a list of mp3's and loop over that list.

Comment: @LjmDullaart could you please help me out and elaborate on it? It would help me a lot.

Comment: can you show us what youve tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

As in the comment: use `find` to create a list of the mp3-files:

```
find /top/dir/for/mp3s -name '*mp3'
```

You will want to use that output to loop over it, so:

```
find /top/dir/for/mp3s -name '*mp3' | while read mp3file, do
    # do the linking
done
```

You want create a link in a specific directory, probably with the same filename. You can get the filename with `basename`. So, that would make it something like this:

```
find /top/dir/for/mp3s -name '*mp3' | while read mp3file; do
    filename=$(basename $mp3file)
    ln -s $mp3file /dir/where/the/links/are/$filename
    echo Linked $mp3file to /dir/where/the/links/are/$filename
done
```

However, this will probably give you two types of error:

- If the mp3 filename contains spaces, `basename` will not produce the correct filename and `ln` will complain. Solution: use correct quoting.
- If you have duplicate filenames, `ln` will complain that the link already exists. Solution: test if the link exists.

Because you're not destroying anything, you can try it and actually see the problems. So, our next iteration would be:

```
find /top/dir/for/mp3s -name '*mp3' | while read mp3file; do
    filename=$(basename "$mp3file")
    if [ ! -l "/dir/where/the/links/are/$filename" ] ; then
        ln -s "$mp3file" "/dir/where/the/links/are/$filename"
        echo "Linked $mp3file to /dir/where/the/links/are/$filename"
    else
        echo "Not linked $mp3file; link exists"
    fi
done
```

That should give you a fairly good result. It also gives you a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much! I’ll get into it as soon as I get home.